# Database structure and query building

Tags: database, database-design, backend

Please advise how to accomplish this task.

There is an entity - the user.
He can create a group in which there will be other users with certain rights.

Here I'm interested in how to correctly cost requests to get groups for the user and guest.

I assume that the group will have corresponding fields for which I will make a selection, but I don’t really understand how to properly store the role of the guest in this group. I have one idea, but I'm not sure if it's ok.

```
interface Group {
  id: string;
  ownerId: string;
  guestsId: string[];
  // or my idea :)
  guests: Array<{
    guestId: string;
    role: string;
  }>
}
```

Perhaps you need to create another table for this? I am using relational db

Same way. Question number 2.
Each user has a photo, and each group has pictures.

I need to restrict access to pictures (getting will be through api with middleware, not static) for different users.

1. Pictures in a group can only be viewed by its members.
2. A user's photo can be seen if you are in the same group with him.

I don't have many ideas here. I see the problem that in order to get a picture, you need to check which groups the user who requested the picture belongs to.

All that came to mind is when generating a jwt token, get a list of user groups and add them to this token.
But I'm not sure.

I would appreciate your ideas and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a database standpoint, I see tables:

**User table**

```
Userid (PK)
UserName
UserPhoto
```

**Group table**

```
Groupid (PK)
GroupName
```

**Rights table**

```
Rightid (PK)
RightName
```

**Picture**

```
Pictureid (PK)
PictureLocation
```

---

Link tables

**Group_has_rights**

```
Groupid (FK)
Rightid (FK)
```

**Group_has_users**

```
Groupid (FK)
Userid (FK)
```

**Groups_has_Pictures**

```
Groupid (FK)
Pictureid (FK)
```

---

Using the **Groups_has_SOMETHING** tables, you establish many-to-many relations.  This way, users, rights and pictures can be associated to many groups.

It gives you complete flexibility for match current and future requirements and combinations.

---

With link tables, this being a relational database, you can use JOIN statements to extract any list of required items.  No need to iterate through lists in your code, the database does it all.

---

For your guest users, I do not understand your requirement.  Define what rights a guest user should have and associate it to a group that has those rights in Groups_has_Rights.

Your application code can associate a guest1, guest2, ... user that is created on the spot, with a link to the appropriate group(s).

---

For your pictures, you get the list of groups for the current user in Groups_has_User.  Then you get a list of pictures to display through Groups_has_Pictures, for the groups you listed above.  Use JOIN in your SQL.

---

For the photos, you get the list of groups for the current user in Groups_has_User.  From that list, you get a list of all other users that are in the same groups, again from Groups_has_User.  Then from the users list, you select the UserPhoto.  Again, use JOIN in your SQL.

---

Obviously this only shows the basic structure of tables and relations.  Each table will contain more information, I just demonstrated the squeleton.